# Is Flash development for Android below 2.2 feasible?

Tags: android

Apparently you need to install AIR in your mobile to use Flash apps, and AIR requires Android 2.2 while my Milestone is a feeble 2.1.update1.

There is seriously no Flash lite or other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash for Android 2.1 Download:

> http://www.androidapk.net/?p=53

A Comparison Between FlashLite 4 on Android 2.1 vs Flash 10.1 beta on Android 2.2 can seen here:

> http://www.dailymobile.se/2010/05/23/flash-lite-4-on-android-2-1-vs-flash-10-1-beta-on-android-2-2/

How to install Flash Player 10.1 on Android 2.1:

> http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-flash-10-1-on-android-2-1-eclair-devices/

Comment: I guess this is as good an answer as I'll get. Thanks.